# Inheritance in PlayOrm

Tags: playorm

I am not able to understand the use of Annotation "@NoSqlDiscriminatorColumn". Can someone please explain if it always required? If yes, why? 
If no, then in the unit tests, Account extends AccountSuper.. is it also another example of inheritance? What is the difference between this and the entities used in TestInheritanceSingleTable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to store information on which subclass was saved so when we read it back in, we use the correct subclass.  This information is stored in a specific column(you tell us which column with @NoSqlDiscriminatorColumn) so basically this pattern adds a column that is not in your entities.  With this pattern, you can have N subclasses all in the same table.

Account extending AccountSuper is nothing special.  That is not storing different entities in the same table.  That is only storing Accounts.  It just happens Accounts extends AccountSuper so it stores any fields in Account and any fields in AccountSuper so basically all rows in the Account table are generally the same size.  In the inheritance example, we are storing different entities so those different entities probably result in different row lengths as each will have different numbers of columns.

Comment: thanks for this..but unfortunately I am still not able to understand that how it will be stored. 
Let us compare with Hibernate. In Hibernate, there are 3 ways, 
1. Table per concrete class with unions
2. Table per class hierarchy
3. Table per subclass

So for Manager and Worker entities, both of  which extend Employee. 1st method will require 3 tables, 2nd method will require a single table and 3rd need 2 tables. How many table(s) we will require in playorm?

Comment: Ok, I dig it further and got the answer it seems. Could you confirm my understanding. If we give NoSqlDiscriminatorColumn for Manager and Worker, it will have a single table in database (For Employee).i.e., like Option number 2 in above hibernate example.

However, if I do not give NoSqlDiscriminatorColumn then, it will have separate table for each subclass. i.e., option number 3 in hibernate example above.

Comment: We only support 2. Table per clas hierarchy so basically it all goes in one table.  I don't see a need for multiple tables as of yet since rows in noSQL don't store nulls like RDBMS so RDBMS needed more options.